# Why does the ToolTip not display in the WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, webbrowser-control

I assigned a `ToolTip` value to a `WebBrowser` control, but the tool tip is not displaying.

```
// Create the ToolTip and associate with the Form container.
ToolTip toolTip2 = new ToolTip();

// Set up the delays for the ToolTip.
toolTip2.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
toolTip2.InitialDelay = 3000;
toolTip2.ReshowDelay = 500;

// Force the ToolTip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
toolTip2.ShowAlways = true;

// Set up the ToolTip text for the Button and Checkbox.
toolTip2.SetToolTip(this.WebBrowser1, "My Web Browser");
```

Comment: i would display a tooltip in the browser interfere with the website

Comment: I want the tooltip appears when the mouse pointer and point to a link and contains the URL of this link

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip that you want to display must be part of your HTML page. You use the [**Title**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) attribute. For example:

```
 <p><abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.</p>

 <a  title="Click on me"  href="http://blah" target="_self">I am a link</a>
```

The WebBrowser control will automatically display your tooltip when you hover the mouse over it.